# Mutex causes access violation when debugging - works fine otherwise

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

The following `Bar()` function has never caused me any trouble:

```
class Foo {
public:
  void Bar();
private:
  std::mutex mutex_;
};

void Foo::Bar() {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ mutex_ };
  // ...
}
```

Now, I have a unit test to cover `Bar()` - using GTest. The test passes just fine, but when I try to debug it I get an `Exception thrown: read access violation` in the line with the unique lock.

The code that breaks is in `mutex.c`:

```
if (mtx->thread_id != static_cast<long>(GetCurrentThreadId()))
   mtx->_get_cs()->lock();
```

Here `_get_cs()` returns something uninitialized.

**Questions:**

1) Can you help me understand this or point me into the right direction?

2) Do I need to worry about this?

**What works and what doesn't work:**

- Running the application as a command line application: **works** (no access violation)
- Debugging the application from Visual Studio: **works** (let's me step over the line with the unique lock)
- Running the application as a Windows service and attaching the debugger: **works**
- Running the unit test from within Visual Studio (with ReSharper): **works**
- Running the unit test from the command line: **works**
- Debugging the unit test from Visual Studio (with ReSharper): **crashes**

Comment: Somehow, you managed to call `Bar` on an uninitialized or already-destroyed instance of `Foo`.

Comment: What's different between the application and the unit test?  Is the unit test using a global `Foo` object?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Thank you for your help! I pretty much can rule that out. The object is a function local object of my test function: `auto foo = std::make_shared<Foo>{ ... }`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: I don't see any real differences. In the application `Foo` is a `shared_ptr` of the main function, in the test it's in the test function. I really suspect that it's some trickery that ReSharper is doing behind the scenes, but that suspicion alone didn't help me come up with a search that yielded any results..